# Python Project- A population model

Tags: python-3.4

I'm a very inexperienced programmer and was wondering if any of you could spot what is wrong with my code? I have been tearing my hair out over it. Any help would be appreciated. Also is it a basic error or more complex?

In addition, do you know how I could proceed in fix the RunModel function. Theoretically, it should work however the model only prints a whole load of zeroes in its place?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random
import sys


Gen0J = 0 
Gen0A = 0 
Gen0S = 0 
SRJ = 0 
SRA = 0 
SRS = 0 
BirthRate = 0 
GenNo = 0 
NewJ = Gen0J
NewA = Gen0A
NewS = Gen0S
total = NewJ + NewA + NewS 


#Print Table Function
def print_table(table):
            col_width = [max(len(str(x)) for x in col) for col in zip(*table)]
            for line in table:
                  print("| " + " | ".join("{:{}}".format(x, col_width[i])

                                          for i, x in enumerate(line)) + " |")

def menu():
    print("-----Welcome to the AQA Population Model-----\n")
    print("1: Set the Generation 0 values")
    print("2: Display the Generation 0 values")
    print("3: Run the model")
    print("4: Export data")
    print("5: Quit")
    UserInput = int(input("\nPlease select the option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5:"))

    while UserInput != 1 and UserInput != 2 and UserInput != 3 and UserInput != 4 and UserInput != 5:
        UserInput = int(input("Invalid input\nPlease select option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5")) #prompt for user to re-enter their choice

        #selection enables the user to access their desired part of the menu
        if UserInput == 1:#if the user selected option 1, the gen0_values function will be called
            Gen0Set() 
        elif UserInput == 2: #if the user selected option 2, the display_gen0 function will be called
            print("") 
            table = [['Generation', 'Juveniles', 'Adults', 'Seniles', 'Total'],
                 [0, Gen0J, Gen0A, Gen0S, (Gen0J + Gen0S + Gen0A)]]
            print_table(table)
            print("The number of individuals are measured in thousands\n")
            menu()
            DisplayGen0()
        elif UserInput == 3: #if the user selected option 3, the model will be run
            print("")
            print("Generation\tJuveniles\tAdults\t\tSeniles\t\tTotal\n")
            RunModel()
        elif UserInput == 4: #if the user selected option 4, they can export the data
            print()
            ExportData()
        else: #if the user selected option 5, the program will end
            exit()

def Gen0Set():
    global Gen0J, Gen0A, GenoS, SRJ, SRA, SRS, BirthRate, GenNo
    print("NOTE: The greenflies will be measured in thousands")
    print("NOTE: The survival rate should be a value between 0 and 1 (a decimal number)")
    #Gen0J = Generation 0 juvenile values
    Gen0J=float(input("What is the initial number of Juveniles? (In thousands)\n"))
    #Gen0A = Generation 0 adult values
    Gen0A=float(input("What is the initial number of Adults? (In thousands)\n"))
    #Gen0S = Generation 0 senile values
    Gen0S=float(input("What is the initial number of Seniles? (In thousands)\n"))
    #SRJ = Survival rate of juveniles. Float is used as the number could be a decimal.
    SRJ = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Juveniles?\n"))
    while SRJ < 0 or SRJ > 1:
        print ("Invalid input")
        SRJ = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Juveniles?\n"))
    #SRA = Survival rate of adults. Float is used as the number could be a decimal.
    SRA = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Adults?\n"))
    #While loop is used to stop user entering invalid inputs
    while SRA < 0 or SRA > 1:
        print ("Invalid input")
        SRA = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Adults?\n"))
    #SRS = Survival rate of seniles. Float is used as the number could be a decimal.
    SRS = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Seniles?\n"))
    #While loop is used to stop user entering invalid inputs
    while SRS < 0 or SRS > 1:
        print ("Invalid input")
        SRS = float(input("What is the survival rate of the Seniles?\n"))
    BirthRate = float(input("What is the Birth Rate?\n"))
    total = Gen0J + Gen0A + Gen0S
    print("\nWhat is the number of New Generations to the model? This number should be between 5 and 25 inclusive.\n")
    while True:        
        GenNo = int(input("Choose the number you would like to input: \n"))
    while GenNo < 5 or GenNo > 25:
        print("Invalid input")
        GenNo= int(input("The number of generations you would like modelled: "))
        menu()

        return Gen0J, Gen0A, Gen0S, SRJ, SRA, SRS, BirthRate, GenNo




def RunModel():
  global Gen0J, Gen0A, Gen0S, SRJ, SRA, SRA, BirthRate, GenNo, NewJ, NewA, NewS, total
  for gen in range(0, GenNo + 1):
    NewJ = NewA * BirthRate
    NewA = NewJ * SRJ
    NewS = (NewS * SRS) + (NewA * SRA)
    total = NewJ + NewA + NewS
    print (gen, "\t\t", NewJ, "\t\t", NewA, "\t\t", NewS, "\t\t", total) 

def ExportData():
    global Gen0J, Gen0A, Gen0S, SRJ, SRA, SRS, BirthRate, GenNo
    print ("Export Data")
    filename = input("Filename: ")
    while os.path.isfile(filename +".txt"):
        overwrite = int(input ("This filename already exists, do you want to overwrite it?\n Enter 1 for yes and 2 for no"))
        if overwrite == 1:
            filename = filename
            print("The file has been overwritten")
            print("\nThe data has been saved")
        elif overwrite == 2:
            export_data()
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            export_data()
    data = ["JUVENILES",str(Gen0J),"ADULTS",str(Gen0A),"SENILES",str(Gen0S),"JUVENILE SURVIVAL RATE",str(SRJ),"ADULT SURVIVAL RATE",str(SRA),"SENILES SURVIVAL RATE",str(SRS),"BIRTH RATE",str(BirthRate),"GENERATIONS",str(No_of_gen)]
    with open (filename+".txt", mode = "w", encoding = "utf-8") as my_file:
        for item in data:
            my_file.write(item + "\n")
    print("\nThe data has been saved")
    menu()


menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to work quite a bit better if you change your menu function to this:

```
def menu():
    print("-----Welcome to the AQA Population Model-----\n")
    print("1: Set the Generation 0 values")
    print("2: Display the Generation 0 values")
    print("3: Run the model")
    print("4: Export data")
    print("5: Quit")
    UserInput = int(input("\nPlease select the option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5:"))

    if UserInput != 1 and UserInput != 2 and UserInput != 3 and UserInput != 4 and UserInput != 5:
        UserInput = int(input("Invalid input\nPlease select option 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5")) #prompt for user to re-enter their choice

    #selection enables the user to access their desired part of the menu
    if UserInput == 1:#if the user selected option 1, the gen0_values function will be called
        Gen0Set() 
    elif UserInput == 2: #if the user selected option 2, the display_gen0 function will be called
        print("") 
        table = [['Generation', 'Juveniles', 'Adults', 'Seniles', 'Total'],
         [0, Gen0J, Gen0A, Gen0S, (Gen0J + Gen0S + Gen0A)]]
        print_table(table)
        print("The number of individuals are measured in thousands\n")
        menu()
        DisplayGen0()
    elif UserInput == 3: #if the user selected option 3, the model will be run
        print("")
        print("Generation\tJuveniles\tAdults\t\tSeniles\t\tTotal\n")
        RunModel()
    elif UserInput == 4: #if the user selected option 4, they can export the data
        print()
        ExportData()
    elif UserInput == 5: #if the user selected option 5, the program will end
        exit()
    else:
        menu()
```

Comment: you can clean it up even further, but I only tried changing the minimum amount of your code.

Comment: your while loop is kicking you out if you answer with 1-5

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: In addition, do you know how I could proceed in fix the RunModel function. Theoretically, it should work however the model only prints a whole load of zeroes in its place?

Comment: try moving the return back one indent level in the Gen0Set() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def ModelRun():
  global NoOfGenerations
  for gen in range(0, NoOfGenerations + 1):
    global GenerationJuveniles, GenerationAdults, GenerationSeniles, NewJuveniles, NewAdults, NewSeniles, SurvivalRate_Juvenile, SurvivalRate_Adults, SurvivalRate_Seniles, BirthRate, Total

    NewJuveniles = (GenerationAdults) * (BirthRate)
    NewAdults = (GenerationJuveniles) * (SurvivalRate_Juvenile)
    NewSeniles = (GenerationSeniles) * (SurvivalRate_Seniles) + (GenerationAdults) * (SurvivalRate_Adults)
    Total = (NewJuveniles) + (NewAdults) + (NewSeniles)
    print str(gen) + "\t", (NewJuveniles),  "\t", (NewAdults), "\t", (NewSeniles),  "\t", (Total)  

menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
def set_gen_0():
    global Juveniles
    global JuvSurvival
    global Adults
    global AdultSurvival
    global Seniles
    global SenileSurvival
    global BirthRate
    global NumberOfGenerations
    print ("Here you can set your given geration 0 values and other information for the model")
    Juveniles=int(input("Please enter the amount of juveniles\n"))
    JuvSurvival=float(input("Please enter the juvenile survival rate must be between 1 and 0\n"))
    while JuvSurvival>1 or JuvSurvival<0:
        JuvSurvival=float(input("Invalid number, Please enter the juvenile survival rate must be between 1 and 0\n"))
    Adults=int(input("Please enter the amount of adults\n"))
    AdultSurvival=float(input("please enter the adult survival rate must be between 1 and 0\n"))
    while AdultSurvival>1 or AdultSurvival<0:
        AdultSurvival=float(input("Invalid number, Please enter the Adult survival rate must be between 1 and 0\n"))
    Seniles=int(input("Please enter the amount of Seniles\n"))
    SenileSurvival=float(input("Please enter the senile survival rate, number must be between 1 and 0\n"))
    while SenileSurvival>1 or SenileSurvival<0:
        SenileSurvival=float(input("invalid number,please enter the Adult survival rate between 1 and 0\n"))
    BirthRate=float(input("Enter the Birth rate\n"))
    NumberOfGenerations=int(input("Please enter the number of generations you would like the model to run for, must be between 5 and 25\n"))
    while NumberOfGenerations>25 or NumberOfGenerations <5:
        NumberOfGenerations=int(input("Invalid number, must be between 5 and 25\n"))
    menu()
def display_generation0():
    print  ("There are", Juveniles, "Juveniles")
    print  ("The Juvenile Survival rate is", JuvSurvival)
    print  ("There are", Adults, "Adults")
    print  ("The Adult survival rate is", AdultSurvival)
    print  ("There are", Seniles, "Seniles")
    print  ("The Senile survival rate is", SenileSurvival)
    print  ("The Birthrate is", BirthRate)
    print  ("The Model will run for", NumberOfGenerations)
    menu()
def run_model(Adults,Seniles,Juveniles):
    global Wholemodel
    Wholemodel=[]
    Gen0=[]
    TotalPopulation=(Juveniles+Adults+Seniles)
    Gen0=[Juveniles,Adults,Seniles,TotalPopulation]
    Wholemodel.append(Gen0)
    print  ("There are", Juveniles, "Juveniles")
    print  ("There are", Adults, "Adults")
    print  ("There are", Seniles, "Seniles")
    print (Gen0)
    for i in range (NumberOfGenerations):
        NewJuveniles=(Adults*BirthRate)
        NewSeniles=((Seniles*SenileSurvival)+(Adults*AdultSurvival))
        NewAdults=(Juveniles*JuvSurvival)
        TotalPopulation=(NewJuveniles+NewAdults+NewSeniles)
        Gen0=[NewJuveniles, NewAdults, NewSeniles, TotalPopulation]
        Wholemodel.append(Gen0)
        print  ("There are", NewJuveniles, "Juveniles")
        print  ("There are", NewAdults, "Adults")
        print  ("There are", NewSeniles, "Seniles")
        print (Gen0)
        Adults=NewAdults
        Seniles=NewSeniles
        Juveniles=NewJuveniles
    menu()
def export_data(Wholemodel):
    global filename
    filename=input("Enter a Name for the file: ")
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("File exists")                        
        decision=input("Do you wish to overwrite it? ") 
        while decision=="no" or decision=="No":
            filename=input("Choose a new file name: ")
            f=open(filename,"w")                          
            f.write(str(Wholemodel))
            f.close()
            break
        if decision=="yes" or decision=="Yes":
            f=open(filename,"w")               
            f.write(str(Wholemodel))
            f.close()
    else:
        f=open(filename,"w")
        f.write(str(Wholemodel))

        f.close()

def menu():
    print ("Main Menu")
    print ("[1] Set Generation 0 values")
    print ("[2] Display the Generation 0 values")
    print ("[3] Run Model")
    print ("[4] Export data")
    print ("[5] Quit")
    choice= int(input("What would you like to do\n"))
    if choice==1:
        set_gen_0()
    elif choice==2:
        display_generation0()
    elif choice==3:
        run_model(Adults,Seniles,Juveniles)
    elif choice==4:
        export_data(Wholemodel)
    elif choice==5:
                print ("Thanks for using the greenfly population model")
                quit()
menu()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please explain in your answer what the OP did wrong